# What kind of valves are used to prevent flashback in turbine engines?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, flashback

In a college experiment with Small Turbine Engine, we were told about the use of Valves for preventing flashbacks in engines. What are the available valves used for preventing flashbacks and what are the pros and cons of using different kind of flashbacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VERICOR POWER SYSTEMS has a patent for these valves, number `US 6357216 B1` and title `Flashback control for a gas turbine engine combustor having an air bypass system`

The patent includes the following image:

[image: value diagram]

> SUMMARY OF THE INVENTION
>
> An object of the present invention is to provide for a control and method for arresting flashback in a gas turbine engine combustion system having a venturi for delivering a mixture of air and fuel to a combustion chamber and a valve for controlling the amount of air flowing to the venturi.
>
> The present invention achieves this object by providing a flashback control system and method having a flashback detection routine, a valve position trim routine, and a reference flame temperature adjustment routine. The flashback detection routine detects a flashback in the venturi by comparing the temperature at the venturi to the temperature of the air entering the valve. The valve position trim routine receives this flashback signal and in response causes the valve to open until the flashback is arrested. Finally, to prevent the flashback from recurring, the reference flame temperature adjustment routine adjusts a reference flame temperature in the control system so as to prevent the valve from returning to the position at which the flashback occurred.
>
> These and other objects, features and advantages of the present invention, are specifically set forth in, or will become apparent from, the following detailed description of a preferred embodiment of the invention when read in conjunction with the accompanying drawings.

The patent can be viewed here on [Google patents list](https://www.google.com/patents/US6357216), however, it has expired.

Comment: Are there any other options or this is the only one in use?